# Getting a Error: Endpoint read failed when trying to deploy a .bna

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm getting a Error: error trying deploy. Error: error trying install chaincode. Error: Endpoint read failed
when trying to deploy a .bna with Composer.

I have set a connection profile, and imported an admin identity by

**composer identity import -p hlfv1 -u PeerAdmin -c ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem -k ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/c6514cb2a41dbcf44efcaf5c106bf8bed44aa7e1147aea439655d968c792149b_sk**

and then

**composer network deploy -p hlfv1 -a bonusetis.bna -i PeerAdmin -s password**

the connection profile file is

```
   {
    "type": "hlfv1",
    "orderers": [
        {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:7050"
        }
    ],
    "ca": {
        "url": "http://localhost:7054",
        "name": "ca_peerOrg1"
    },
    "peers": [
        {
            "requestURL": "grpc://localhost:7051",
            "eventURL": "grpc://localhost:7053"
        },
        {
            "requestURL": "grpc://localhost:8051",
            "eventURL": "grpc://localhost:8053"
        }
    ],
    "keyValStore": "/home/pere-lluis/.hfc-key-store",
    "channel": "mychannel",
    "mspID": "Org1MSP",
    "timeout": "300"
    }
```

And the log:

```
2017-07-03T14:05:27.515Z INFO    ConnectionProfileManager :constructor()             Created a new ConnectionProfileManager {"0":{"fs":{"constants":{"O_RDONLY":0,"O_WRONLY":1,"O_RDWR":2,"S_IFMT":61440,"S_IFREG":32768,"S_IFDIR":16384,"S_IFCHR":8192,"S_IFBLK":24576,"S_IFIFO":4096,"S_IFLNK":40960,"S_IFSOCK":49152,"O_CREAT":64,"O_EXCL":128,"O_NOCTTY":256,"O_TRUNC":512,"O_APPEND":1024,"O_DIRECTORY":65536,"O_NOATIME":262144,"O_NOFOLLOW":131072,"O_SYNC":1052672,"O_DIRECT":16384,"O_NONBLOCK":2048,"S_IRWXU":448,"S_IRUSR":256,"S_IWUSR":128,"S_IXUSR":64,"S_IRWXG":56,"S_IRGRP":32,"S_IWGRP":16,"S_IXGRP":8,"S_IRWXO":7,"S_IROTH":4,"S_IWOTH":2,"S_IXOTH":1,"F_OK":0,"R_OK":4,"W_OK":2,"X_OK":1},"F_OK":0,"R_OK":4,"W_OK":2,"X_OK":1}}}$
2017-07-03T14:05:27.528Z INFO    FSConnectionProfileStore :save()                    Saved connection profile hlfv1 {}$
2017-07-03T14:05:27.529Z INFO    ConnectionProfileManager :connect()                 Connecting using hlfv1 {"0":null}$
2017-07-03T14:05:27.531Z INFO    FSConnectionProfileStore :load()                    Loaded connection profile hlfv1 {"0":"{\n    \"type\": \"hlfv1\",\n    \"orderers\": [\n        {\n            \"url\": \"grpc://localhost:7050\"\n        }\n    ],\n    \"ca\": {\n        \"url\": \"htp://localhost:7054\",\n        \"name\": \"ca_peerOrg1\"\n    },\n    \"peers\": [\n        {\n            \"requestURL\": \"grpc://localhost:7051\",\n            \"eventURL\": \"grpc://localhost:7053\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"requestURL\": \"grpc://localhost:8051\",\n            \"eventURL\": \"grpc://localhost:8053\"\n        }\n    ],\n    \"keyValStore\": \"/home/pere-lluis/.hfc-key-store\",\n    \"channel\": \"mychannel\",\n    \"mspID\": \"Org1MSP\",\n    \"timeout\": \"300\"\n}"}$
2017-07-03T14:05:27.531Z INFO    ConnectionProfileManager :getConnectionManager()    Looking up a connection manager for profile {"0":"hlfv1"}$
2017-07-03T14:05:27.532Z INFO    FSConnectionProfileStore :load()                    Loaded connection profile hlfv1 {"0":"{\n    \"type\": \"hlfv1\",\n    \"orderers\": [\n        {\n            \"url\": \"grpc://localhost:7050\"\n        }\n    ],\n    \"ca\": {\n        \"url\": \"htp://localhost:7054\",\n        \"name\": \"ca_peerOrg1\"\n    },\n    \"peers\": [\n        {\n            \"requestURL\": \"grpc://localhost:7051\",\n            \"eventURL\": \"grpc://localhost:7053\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"requestURL\": \"grpc://localhost:8051\",\n            \"eventURL\": \"grpc://localhost:8053\"\n        }\n    ],\n    \"keyValStore\": \"/home/pere-lluis/.hfc-key-store\",\n    \"channel\": \"mychannel\",\n    \"mspID\": \"Org1MSP\",\n    \"timeout\": \"300\"\n}"}$
2017-07-03T14:05:28.203Z INFO    ConnectionProfileManager :getConnectionManager()    Using this connection manager  {"0":{"connectionProfileManager":{"connectionProfileStore":{"fs":{"constants":{"O_RDONLY":0,"O_WRONLY":1,"O_RDWR":2,"S_IFMT":61440,"S_IFREG":32768,"S_IFDIR":16384,"S_IFCHR":8192,"S_IFBLK":24576,"S_IFIFO":4096,"S_IFLNK":40960,"S_IFSOCK":49152,"O_CREAT":64,"O_EXCL":128,"O_NOCTTY":256,"O_TRUNC":512,"O_APPEND":1024,"O_DIRECTORY":65536,"O_NOATIME":262144,"O_NOFOLLOW":131072,"O_SYNC":1052672,"O_DIRECT":16384,"O_NONBLOCK":2048,"S_IRWXU":448,"S_IRUSR":256,"S_IWUSR":128,"S_IXUSR":64,"S_IRWXG":56,"S_IRGRP":32,"S_IWGRP":16,"S_IXGRP":8,"S_IRWXO":7,"S_IROTH":4,"S_IWOTH":2,"S_IXOTH":1,"F_OK":0,"R_OK":4,"W_OK":2,"X_OK":1},"F_OK":0,"R_OK":4,"W_OK":2,"X_OK":1}}}}}$
2017-07-03T14:05:40.922Z ERROR   HLFConnection            :_install()                {"message":"error trying install chaincode. Error: Endpoint read failed","stack":"Error: error trying install chaincode. Error: Endpoint read failed\n    at temp.mkdir.then.then.then.then.then.catch (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:367:34)"}$
```

And docker ps gives:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
100ae9868898        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."   16 seconds ago       Up 12 seconds       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                             ca_peerOrg1
05205477777e        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."   16 seconds ago       Up 13 seconds       0.0.0.0:8054->7054/tcp                             ca_peerOrg2
13f6085efbbe        hyperledger/fabric-tools     "/bin/bash"              About a minute ago   Up About a minute                                                      cli
30682de3757e        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:9051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9053->7053/tcp     peer0.org2.example.com
bace9d430a0d        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:10051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10053->7053/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
347d902ef369        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                             orderer.example.com
e125d8cb1f31        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp     peer0.org1.example.com
463ecc4146eb        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp     peer1.org1.example.com
```

Comment: I'm working on latest versions of composer and fabric (0.9 and beta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lluis, have you got TLS enabled in your configuration? If so, you can read the docs on creating a connection profile using the full format (eg grpcs:// etc) -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/connectionprofile.html .

Comment: How do I know if TLS is enabled? Is it by default? Also, if it is, do you have to add the TLS crypto generated for each peer?Sorry if the question seems silly, but I got it working in 0.8.1 without adding anything about TLS, and I followed the same steps, that's why I ask. Thanks

Comment: How have you defined your local fabric ? You aren't using the development server provided by composer which doesn't have tls enabled, so you have created your own fabric environment most likely with tls enabled and appropriately configured.

Comment: All correct now, as u mentioned it seemed to be a problem with TLS. It's weird cause it didn't gave me trouble with 0.8. 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the procedure to overcome this error? I am getting the same error when deploying BNA file on a network I have set up. I followed the standard procedure of hyperledger to set up from their documentation.

Comment: As I recall, you have to edit the .yml, where TLS is enabled, and disable it. If you need TLS, then you would have to provide all the crypto necessary.